# Search multidimensional array that contains both 2 needles using php

Tags: php, elasticsearch, search, multidimensional-array

I need to search into an array, returning all elements that contains both 2 values i'm searching, like this:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'Joel first',
        'title' => 'teacher',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'Joel second',
        'title' => 'teacher',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'Jhon first',
        'title' => 'teacher',
    )
);
```

I want to search for all elements that contains name like **Joel** AND title like **teacher**, similar to mysql search like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like 'Joel%' AND title = 'teacher'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filtering items of array.

```
$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($val){
    return substr($val['name'], 0, 4) == 'Joel' && $val['title'] == 'teacher';
});
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/25Poe)